# Codeigniter upload image file with array field name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I'm quite new to the codeigniter library and function. Recently i had a form that had a few dynamic input field to be submit and insert into database for recording purpose.

The image upload file field was dynamically created if user click "+" button, and i was using array name as the name for the input field. However when i trying to call the controller to upload the file or insert with the array field name, it keep prompted me 'You did not select a file to upload'.

If i change the image field's input name to only 'reg_photo' and the do upload field name to 'reg_photo' then everything working fine but that is not i wanted because i wanted to upload it based on the dynamic input array.

I did try to look around the solution at stackoverflow and google but after i try and none of it could help me.

Here are my Controller to do the upload :

```
 //Upload Picture Configuration
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/profile_picture/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']             = 2048;
        $config['max_width']            = 1920;
        $config['max_height']           = 1080;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        //Check and get the Areas list
        $areaList = $this->input->post('areas', true);
        $finalSeparator = $areaList;
        $resultArea = "";
        foreach ($finalSeparator as $i => $a) {
            if (next($finalSeparator )) {
                $resultArea .= $a.','; // Add comma for all elements instead of last
            }
            else
            {
                $resultArea .= $a;
            }
        }


        if ($this->input->post('reg_name')) { // returns false if no property

            //Get Last Inserted District ID
            $district = "";
            $failedUploadNameList = "";
            $photoPath = "";
            $data = array(
                'district_code' => $this->input->post('reg_district_2', true),
                'district_country' => '',
            );
            $this->db->set('district_registered_date', 'NOW()', FALSE); //Submit current date time
            if($this->Registerlanguage_admin_model->register_district($data))
            {
                $district = $this->db->insert_id(); //Last Get ID

                $name = $this->input->post('reg_name', true);
                $year1 = $this->input->post('reg_year1', true);
                $year2 = $this->input->post('reg_year2', true);
                $nickname = $this->input->post('reg_nickname', true);
                $photo = $this->input->post('reg_photo', true);

                foreach ($name as $i => $a) { // need index to match other properties

                    //Check to whether can upload image or not
                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($photo[$i]))
                    {
                        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                        foreach($error as $q)
                        {
                            $failedUploadNameList .= $q;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data('file_name'));

                        foreach($data as $a)
                        {
                            $photoPath = $config['upload_path'].$a;
                        }
                    }
                    $data = array(
                        'area_district_id' => $district,
                        'area_name' => $resultArea,
                        'area_language' =>  $this->input->post('reg_language', true),
                        'area_year_1' => isset($year1[$i]) ? $year1[$i] : '',
                        'area_year_2' => isset($year2[$i]) ? $year2[$i] : '',
                        'area_leader_name' => isset($name[$i]) ? $name[$i] : '',
                        'area_leader_nickname' => isset($nickname[$i]) ? $nickname[$i] : '',
                        'area_leader_photo' => $photoPath
                    );
                    $this->db->set('area_registered_date', 'NOW()', FALSE); //Submit current date time
                    if (!$this->Registerlanguage_admin_model->register_area($data)) {
                        // quit if insert fails - adjust accordingly
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                        redirect('index.php/language_admin/index');
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                // don't redirect inside the loop
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('index.php/language_admin/index');
            }

            //Redirect back once all successfully insert
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Insert Successfully!</div>'.$failedUploadNameList);
            redirect('index.php/language_admin/index');
        }
        else{

            // don't redirect inside the loop
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
            redirect('index.php/language_admin/index');
        }
```

Here are my view code :

```
 <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registerdistrictform");
                            echo form_open_multipart("index.php/registerlanguage_admin/registerDistrict", $attributes);?>
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel panel-info">
                                    <div class="panel-body  panel-group">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input class="form-control" name="reg_language" type="hidden" value="Japanese" />
                                            <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">District ：</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input class="form-control" name="reg_district_1" placeholder="Ex : District 3500" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('reg_district_1'); ?>" required/>
                                                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('reg_district_1'); ?></span><br/>
                                                <input class="form-control" name="reg_district_2" placeholder="Ex : 3500" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('reg_district_2'); ?>" required/>
                                                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('reg_district_2'); ?></span><br/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Area ：</label>
                                            <div id="areaContainer">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                    Area Record #0<input class="form-control" name="areas[]" placeholder="Your Language" type="text" value="" required/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addArea">+</a><br/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id = "profileContainer">
                                    <div class="panel panel-danger">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">Profile #0</div>
                                        <div class="panel-body  panel-group">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Years ：</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="reg_year1[]" placeholder="2015" type="text" value="" required/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-1">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="reg_year2[]" placeholder="2017" type="text" value="" required/><br/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-12 control-label"><u>District Governer</u></label><br/>
                                                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name ：</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="reg_name[]" placeholder="Your Language" type="text" required/><br/>
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nickname ：</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="reg_nickname[]" placeholder="English" type="text" required/><br/>
                                                </div>
                                                <label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Photo ：</label>
                                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                    <input class="form-control" name="reg_photo[]" type="file" required/><br/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="pull-right">
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addProfile">+</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body  panel-group">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-sm-1 text-left">
                                            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" >Submit</button>
                                            <!--                <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
                        </div>
```

The 'reg_photo[]' are dynamically insert into HTML if user press the '+' button, so if i change to 'reg_photo' which is not dynamic anymore then it work, what should i do if i wanted to use the 'reg_photo[]' as a field name to upload my file? Please guide me through this. Thank! :)

Comment: $photo = $_FILES['reg_photo'];  file should be accessed from $_FILES not form post value

Comment: @JYoThI Let me try it out, so the field name inside the do_upload still remain as $photo[$i] right?

Comment: yes of course @Marcus

Comment: @JYoThI still same prompted out 'You did not select a file to upload.'

Comment: first var_dump($_FILES['reg_photo']);  exit; and know the file is posted to server or not

Comment: @JYoThI is correct. not only that line, u shud also change `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($photo[$i]))` line too...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju what should i change it to??

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you use here??

Comment: @HarshPanchal I'm using codeigniter 3.1.4

Comment: @JYoThI Here are my result for var dump.
array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "c91a90be-c186-425a-90fe-ec6c37f33b4f.jpg" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpE74A.tmp" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(51398) } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to upload image

```
     $directory = "./images/";
     $config['upload_path']   = $directory; 
     $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; 
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
     if (!$this->upload->do_upload('mainimage'))
     {          
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
        print_r($error);
     }
     else { 
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data()); 
        print_r($data);
     }
```

And one other change is :
Replace upload.php file.
take latest verison upload.php file from system directory -> libraries directory -> upload.php. Copy new version upload.php file and replace in your project

Hope it will work properly.

Comment: but your code was only for single upload right? My code was fine with single upload, but not working if multiple upload

Comment: try to replace upload.php file

Comment: I'm currently using the latest codeigniter. Which upload.php do you mean

Comment: in system directory -> libraries directory -> upload.php.

Comment: this will not upload array files read the question then answer

Comment: you don't understand what i say

Comment: @HarshPanchal what you do you want me to replace the upload.php? I don'y find any upload.php on the library directory

Comment: see my path :

Your project directory->system directory -> libraries directory -> upload.php

Comment: @HarshPanchal Alright, i found it. So what you want me to replace it with?

Comment: latest version upload.php replace there

Comment: @HarshPanchal 3.1.4 is not the latest??

Comment: @HarshPanchal I'm already using the 3.1.4 then i had no need to upgrade the upload.php already. Any other method?

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
* Code above omitted purposely
* In your HTML form, your input[type=file] must be named *upl_files[]*
*/
/*
* Uploads multiple files creating a queue to fake multiple upload calls to
* $_FILE
*/
public function multiple_upload()
{
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['upl_files']['name']);
    // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++){
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['upl_files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['upl_files']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['upl_files']['size'][$i];
        $config = array(
            'file_name'     => <your ouw function to generate random names>,
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'max_size'      => 3000,
            'overwrite'     => FALSE,

            /* real path to upload folder ALWAYS */
            'upload_path'
            => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/upload/folder'
        );
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }else {
            $final_files_data[] = $this->upload->data();
            // Continue processing the uploaded data
        }
    }
}
```

**This Worked for me**. reffer to this page this is not my code 
https://gist.github.com/zitoloco/1558423